# jQuery getting back NaN and [object Object] from variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function, nan

I have some problems getting my script to work. My script calculates the number of orders and the weight of each order. My form is actually created by javascript when pressed the "New Line" button. I am trying to make it so whenever 3 values (number of items, number of items in a box, number of boxes per order) are filled in, it automatically gives you the total number of orders. Also, when given the weight of a single item, it gives you the total weight of the order. All this happens on keyup using jquery. I need help only in the javaScript part. I handle my form with AJAX later on and everything worked but it broke when I tried to implement this.

Whenever I use alert() to see what values my code is assigning to the updateForm() function I get for alert($totalitems) -> [object Object] and alert($weightperpal) -> NaN. Could anybody help me solve this? Heres my code:

HTML:

```
<button id="addLine" type="submit" class="btn red">Add Line</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#addLine").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    lineNum++;

    var cont = '<div class="control-group">'+
        '<label class="control-label">Total # of items</label>'+
        '<div class="controls">'+
        '<input type="text" placeholder="" class="m-wrap medium orderField" name="totalitems'+lineNum+'" id="totalitF" no="'+ lineNum +'"/>'+
        '<span class="help-inline" style="font-size:10px; font-style:italic;">Not mandatory</span>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="control-group">'+
        '<label class="control-label">Items per box</label>'+
        '<div class="controls">'+
        '<input type="text" placeholder="0" class="m-wrap medium orderField" name="ipb'+lineNum+'" id="itemspbF" no="'+ lineNum +'"/>'+
        '<span class="help-inline" style="font-size:10px; font-style:italic;">#</span>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="control-group">'+
        '<label class="control-label">Boxes per order</label>'+
        '<div class="controls">'+
        '<input type="text" placeholder="0" class="m-wrap medium orderField" name="bpp'+lineNum+'" id="boxesppF" no="'+ lineNum +'"/>'+
        '<span class="help-inline" style="font-size:10px; font-style:italic;">#</span>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="control-group">'+
        '<label class="control-label">Weight per Item</label>'+
        '<div class="controls">'+
        '<input type="text" placeholder="0" class="m-wrap medium orderField" name="wpi'+lineNum+'" id="weightpiF" no="'+ lineNum +'"/>'+
        '<span class="help-inline" style="font-size:10px; font-style:italic;">#</span>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="control-group">'+
        '<label class="control-label">Total number of Orders</label>'+
        '<div class="controls">'+
        '<input type="text" placeholder="" class="m-wrap medium orderField" name="pallets'+lineNum+'" id="palletsF" no="'+ lineNum +'"/>'+
        '<span class="help-inline" style="font-size:10px; font-style:italic;"># of pallets</span>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="control-group">'+
        '<label class="control-label">Weight per order</label>'+
        '<div class="controls">'+
        '<input type="text" placeholder="" class="m-wrap medium orderField" name="wpp'+lineNum+'" id="weightppF" no="'+ lineNum +'"/>'+
        '<span class="help-inline" style="font-size:10px; font-style:italic;">Total number of boxes</span>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

    $(document).on('keyup','.weightpiF',function(){
        var valueField = $(this).attr('no');
        updateFormRoe(valueField);
    });
    $(document).on('keyup','.weightppF',function(){
        var valueField = $(this).attr('no');
        updateFormRoe(valueField);

    });
    $(document).on('keyup','.itemspbF',function(){
        var valueField = $(this).attr('no');
        updateFormRoe(valueField);
    });
    $(document).on('keyup','.boxesppF',function(){
        var valueField = $(this).attr('no');
        updateFormRoe(valueField);
    });

    function updateFormRoe(number){
        alert(number);
        var $totalitems = $('#totalitF'+number);
        alert($totalitems);
        var $itemspb = $('#itemspbF'+number).val();

        var $boxespp = $('#boxesppF'+number).val();

        var $weightperitem = $('#weightpiF'+number).val();

        var $itemsinpallet = $itemspb * $boxespp;

        var $totalpals = $totalitems / $itemsinpallet;

        var $weightperpal = ($itemsinpallet) * $weightperitem;
        alert($weightperpal);
        if($totalitems !== '' && $itemspb !== '' && $boxespp !== ''){
            if($totalpals == Infinity){
                $('#palletsF'+number).val('0');
            }else{
                $('#palletsF'+number).val($totalpals);  
            }

            $('#weightppF'+number).val($weightperpal);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remember to wrap `$(...).val()` in `parseFloat(...)` in order to convert the value into a number.

Comment: also use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` to see what's in the objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your selectors like `$('#totalitF'+number)` will work, because you're not appending numbers to your IDs. Instead of:

```
id="totalitF" no="'+ lineNum +'"/>'
```

it should be:

```
id="totalitF'+ lineNum +'" data-no="'+ lineNum +'"/>'
```

You shouldn't create your own attributes. If you want to add additional attributes to an element, use `data-` attributes. Then in jQuery you can access this as

```
$(this).data('no')
```

to get the value. Use this in your other functions in place of `$(this).attr('no')`.

Comment: so I should get rid of the extra 'no' attribute in my inputs and just generate the dynamically with id="totalitF'+ lineNum +'"/>' ?

Comment: Actually, I see that you use `.attr('no')` in your other functions, so you need both of them. See my updated answer.